# Testing Mouse left and right button clicks in C++

Tags: .net, c++

I want to test left and right buttons of mouse  in C++.

I have float variable its value is **100.00f**,If I click left button,its value will increase **1.5f**.

When I click  right button,its value will  decrease **1.5f**.

How can I do this?

Could you help me please?

Best Regards...

Comment: Please, specify your platform/environment. There is no definition of "mouse" in ISO C++ standard.

Comment: My platform is Visual Studio 2008.net.

Answer (score 2):

There is a .NET tag, so I assume we are talking about .NET.

The event you are interested in is [MouseClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick.aspx)

Here is a C#(I'm sorry it is not C++) example how to detect which button is pressed

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        yourVar += 1.5;
    else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        yourVar -= 1.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you'll probably want to handle the mouse button events - to do this I'd refer to plenty of [examples](http://www.codeproject.com/?cat=3) on how to do this.

After you've added you mouse button handlers, sometimes it's a good idea to check for whether the user has swapped their mouse buttons - you do this by querying SM_SWAPBUTTON using [`GetSystemMetrics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724385%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

How I personally I would do this would be using SFML, since it can very easily handle mouse clicks in the GUI window. Not sure how it would be possible in a command prompt window. But I know you could use [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) to do this using C++.